# How to fiter non SSH traffic in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, ssh

I am trying to monitor behaviour of packets from my PC -> VirtualBox machine which represents a virtual router, and I have established SSH session to it.

My question is, how to filter out **all** SSH traffic from displaying and monitor other protocols ?

So far, the filter that I am using:

```
ip.addr == 10.0.0.31 && tcp.port != 22 && not ssh
```

is showing me ACK packets, and somehow it isn't "filtered" completely.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ACK packets are not recognised as SSH packets, so the "not ssh" part of your filter doesn't match on them.

How about simply using

```
ip.addr == 10.0.0.31 && tcp.port != 22
```

Comment: Here are your results : http://imgur.com/a/NzexM .Maybe I wasn't clear, but I don't want to see any client->server ssh communication.

Comment: It's almost there: ip.addr == 10.0.0.31 && !(tcp.port == 22)

Comment: @JaapKeuter Perfect. This is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. For more info why this works, read this part[1] of the manual.


  [1]: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html#ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterMistake

Comment: @JaapKeuter Thanks man. Much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
ip.src==155.85.79.321 && !(tcp.port == 22) && !ssh
```

Exclude a port

```
!(tcp.port == 22)
```

The last no ssh can not be needed!